# TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 upgrade (PHP fsockopen)

Tags: php, paypal, https, tls1.2, fsockopen

I am new to PHP & PayPal and trying to figure it out whether I need to upgrade TLS or not according to the following PayPal article:  https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914

To verify the system I am using **tlstest.paypal.com** endpoint as follows:

```
$header = '';
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: tlstest.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$paypaladdr = 'tlstest.paypal.com';
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$paypaladdr, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

I am getting the response below right away:

```
HTTP/1.1  200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 20
Connection: keep-alive
```

Then after a couple of minutes (6-8) minutes I am getting:
    *PayPal_Connection_OK*

Do you know why is taking so long to receive the *PayPal_Connection_OK* message?
I hope this will not happen for the production endpoint.
Am I good to go?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As long you get the connection_ok from PayPal server, the connection is good to go.

thank you.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  I also have some code that checks if the $result is "VERIFIED" and the code never gets there.  Why?  Is it because of the test endpoint?